# Are there any plants that retrieve energy from the wind?

Tags: evolution, botany, plant-physiology, plant-anatomy

Many trees grow in windy places, but appear to have adapted to this by developing characteristics that provide resistance to wind.

Are there any plants that appear to have been selected for the ability to obtain appreciable amounts of energy from wind, apart from propagation of spores and seeds?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there known life forms that are able to transform mechanical energy into chemical energy?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/62579/are-there-known-life-forms-that-are-able-to-transform-mechanical-energy-into-che)

Comment: Worldbuilding has a version of this question, [for your interest](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/112711/could-plants-generate-energy-using-wind-power).